# CPU-bound very simple app : which stack for high traffic?

Tags: http, redis, rabbitmq

well met !

I have this very basic app that i'm currently running with a LAMP stack which does the following :

-Accept HTTP request

-Manipulate cookies

-Pull data from (local) Redis

-Get the request country from apache_geoip

-Do some very basic business logic with the http request and all the according request/cookie/redis data

-Publish message to (remote) rabbitMQ

-Output <1kb of HTML

So far i'm having "OK" results with this setup, handling peaks of about 800 requests/s with an average response time of like 150ms.
I currently need to improve this to handle more requests/s and response time.
I would like to know if anyone can advise on a stack that would be more efficient to suit this task?

I know this question is a bit of a longshot and apart from testing all kinds of language/webservers i have no clue on how to determine that.
Any help would be more than welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

800rps is not bad at all, but you don't specified your environment and hardware, so without that no one can even give you any specific advise instead of general one like "cache geoip result", etc. (but it may be useless though).

You have to profile your app to see bottleneck and only after that make a decision are there any troubles on app level or you need just second (or N+1th) machine been added to your cluster (if any).

*P.S.:*

If you are using Apache and php (and there are no hard dependenices) try to replace them with nginx and php-fpm.

Sometimes adding simple HTTP caching mechanism helps to reduce requests number significantly (so your server will not do monkey job every time and will handle only 'unique' request).

Comment: Hi, tahnks for the answer ! I said i was using a LAMP stack so my language is obviously PHP

Comment: I realize how i can optimize the existing app and identify its weaknesses, but that is not the point of my question (i understand i wasn't very clear, so sorry about that).
Basically i want to try to get out of apache/php to get something that is faster and more efficient for this specific set of tasks.
I'm looking for a lightweight stack that will respond faster and consume less resources than my current php/apache setup.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer. Basically, this question is too general, so there are no exact answer what to do (IMHO). Sometimes adding simple HTTP caching mechanism helps to reduce requests number significantly.